# convert snake_case keyed map to camelCase keyed map in elixir, phoenix before sending stuff as JSON

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to change keys of maps in elixir from snake case to camel case before sending stuff as JSON. How can I do that? Should it be just a function in which I will wrap every response or should it be done on some lower level, i.e. in Poison?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Many don't know that this is built-into Elixir:

```
iex> Macro.underscore "SAPExample"
"sap_example"

iex> Macro.camelize "sap_example"
"SapExample"

iex> Macro.camelize "hello_10"
"Hello10"
```

See `Macro.underscore/1` [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#underscore/1) or the [implementation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ec65f8d48a602aff78bbde025532a7a875a1555f/lib/elixir/lib/macro.ex#L1595)

Comment: Cheers! I thought that it should be in the language, just did not expect it to be in Macro module :)

Comment: Thats because it should not be used from general libraries. 
`Do not use it as a general mechanism for camelizing strings as it does not support Unicode or characters that are not valid in Elixir identifiers.`

Comment: the title of the question says "camelCase" but these examples don't include a string of that format (lowercased first-letter). To me, this shouldn't be the accepted answer until the question title is edited.

Answer (score 8):

One might use `Macro.underscore/1`, but that's not correct way to do it. Since the `Macro` module itself [states](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4aa81645b0588b56fb61cd154dcaee354732aa5c/lib/elixir/lib/macro.ex#L1265):

> This function was designed to underscore language identifiers/tokens,
>     that's why it belongs to the `Macro` module. Do not use it as a general
>     mechanism for underscoring strings as it does not support Unicode or
>     characters that are not valid in Elixir identifiers.

So, it is better to use some other library. I would recommend to use [`recase`](https://github.com/sobolevn/recase). It can convert string to any case, not just `camelCase`.

Since it is a third-party library you need to install it.

1. add this line to `mix.exs` into `deps`: `{:recase, "~> 0.6"}` Make sure to use the latest version!
2. run `mix deps.get`

That's how you use it:

```
Recase.to_camel("some-value")
# => "someValue"

Recase.to_camel("Some Value")
# => "someValue"
```

You can find docs here: https://hexdocs.pm/recase/readme.html

And the repo here: https://github.com/sobolevn/recase

Answer (score 4):

Much better to use the Inflex library: https://github.com/nurugger07/inflex#underscore

```
iex> Inflex.underscore("camelCase")
"camel_case"
```

Comment: this is the opposite of what the question wants.